# Converting String to Date in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue-data-catalog

I am trying to convert 20-NOV-2019  to date in pyspark. I have been trying various methods but with no luck. Some of the methods I tried are below

```
 df= df.select(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(d1.field_dt, 'yyyy-MM-dd')).alias('field_dt'))
   df = df.select(F.to_date('field_dt')).alias('field_dt')
```

Apart from the above two, I have tried various methods from other stackoverflow questions without any luck. Any suggestions on how to approach this would be helpful.

Comment: I think there is a problem with the date format you used, just change it to 'dd-MM-yyyy' and then check !

Comment: It is showing still null values.

Comment: try this  : dd-MMM-yyyy